# What's the name of this plug?

Tags: identification, connector, breadboard

This is the plug on the MH-Z19B Carbon Dioxide Monitor Sensor. What is this plug called? We need to find a breakout board for it (header?), a connector we can plug that into that have pins that are further apart that can fit in a breadboard. Is this just a standard JST 7 pin connector? There seem to be different versions of this, where the distance (pitch?) of the pins are further apart and also the size of the pins? How do we make sure we get the right thing? How do we figure out the pitch?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried measuring the pitch?

Comment: it's a 7 pin jst connector of some sort. You can probably also use dupont connectors if there's no mechanical stress or movement on the connection.

Comment: also, if you have the cable, you can just chop it and terminate it however you need to. It looks like 5/7 pins are broken out on the unit's PCB's plated through-hole annular rings behind the connectors, trace them with a DMM in beeper mode.

Comment: You can buy a few sizes and return the ones that don't fit if you're in a hurry and have to order online. you didn't get that idea from me...

Comment: Looks like a JST XH or EH or one of those. They're hard to tell apart without dimensions.

Comment: The pitch is 1.25mm according to the [manual](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/mh-z19c-pins%26terminal-type-co2-manual(ver1_2).pdf).

Comment: I have asked the manufacturer for you. If they respond with adequate detail, I will provide the information in the form of an answer. Given the time zones, it will be at least 10 or 12 hours.

Answer (score 2):

My [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p2&s=101148) identifies the header as an [Amphenol MINITEK®1.25 P/N 101148](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/minitek1-25-1011483110107lf.html).

[image: Amphenol FCI 10114831-10107LF]

This picture (from Digikey) is for the 5-pin version. I couldn't find a picture for the 7-pin version. Note the square openings at the bottom: they match yours.

The plug, [Amphenol 10114826-00007LF](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-cs-fci/10114826-00007LF/7592794), also matches your picture.

[image: 10114826-00007LF]

{Digikey}

Note the square holes in the plug: that plug is for square pins, not for blades. Hence, your connector is not a Molex Picoblade.

Answer (score 0):

Page 4 of the manual shows 0.1" pin headers soldered directly onto tabs on both ends of the module.  Unfortunately, the two rows are not on exact 0.1" centers; they are 1.16" apart.  If you angle both rows, the module should plug into a standard protoboard without cables.

If the pins on standard 0.1" headers are too stiff, then use a standard header on one end and five pieces of #20 or #22 wire on the other.  These should bend easily in a short zig-zag to align with protoboard holes.